# JSON array parsing into rows

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle12c

I have JSON as below,

```json
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "createdDateTime": "2021-09-17T14:15:18Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "124",
      "createdDateTime": "2022-09-17T14:15:18Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

am trying to get the output as 2 separate records and store it in clob column(values), any help would be appreciated.

> | values |
> | --- |
> | {"id": "123", "createdDateTime": "2021-09-17T14:15:18Z" } |
> | {"id": "123", "createdDateTime": "2021-09-17T14:15:18Z" } |

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON_TABLE`:

```sql
SELECT j.value
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.json_value,
         '$.value[*]'
         COLUMNS
           value VARCHAR2(4000) FORMAT JSON PATH '$'
       ) j
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (json_value CLOB CHECK (json_value IS JSON));

INSERT INTO table_name (json_value)
VALUES ('{"value":[{
            "id": "123",
            "createdDateTime": "2021-09-17T14:15:18Z"
            
        },
        {
            "id": "124",
            "createdDateTime": "2022-09-17T14:15:18Z"
            
        }]}')
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | {"id":"123","createdDateTime":"2021-09-17T14:15:18Z"} |
> | {"id":"124","createdDateTime":"2022-09-17T14:15:18Z"} |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a4769079c1e3486288e52a32ed25374e)*

Comment: Thank you, it works.